# How to get cell type in POI HSSF Event based parsing

Tags: excel, apache, event-handling, apache-poi, xls

I am using apache POI Event based parsing for XLS file as described in link

http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/how-to.html#Event+API+%28HSSF+Only%29

My XLS file has some date/time cells. Event based parsing seems to treat these cells as number (since NumberRecord is generated). How can I get actual cell type i.e get to know if it was date/time cell or number cell?

Comment: Why not [follow the approach in the Apache POI provided event XLS->CSV converter](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/poi/trunk/src/java/org/apache/poi/hssf/extractor/EventBasedExcelExtractor.java)?

Comment: Many many thanks!! This helps